# What does this error mean with setView: of NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, view, menu, popup

I'm using `setView:` of `NSMenuItem` to customize a menu item, and everything goes happy until I put a pop up button in the content view. When I clicked the button, it didn't pop up its menu and I got the following message.

> Error -25205 for CopyAttributeValue(data, type,
>   (CFStringRef)attribute, &result, NULL) in
>   -[NSAccessibilityAXUIElementWrapper accessibilityAttributeValue:] (line 1928 of file
>   /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1038.35/Accessibility.subproj/NSAccessibilityAPIBridge.m)

Does it mean that we can't pop up one menu over another one? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether there’s a workaround, putting a pop-up menu inside another menu is extremely poor interface. You should find another way of implementing the functionality you desire. What are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe a regular `NSMenuItem` with a submenu would work?

`NSPopover` (new in Lion) or [`MAAttachedWindow`](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass) are much better alternatives for implementing pop-up interfaces like a calendar.

Comment: I want to put a calendar view into menu item, and in the calendar view, I use pop up buttons to select year and month.

Comment: An interface like that doesn’t belong in a menu. I’ve updated my answer with some alternative suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to use pop up window instead of menu.